# How to suppress the Windows crash report dialog results from Mathematica sporadical crash when the code is running

Tags: crash, broken-code

This problem occurs in mathematica 10.0 for windows 7 64 bit.
The dialog box in the center of the picture shows that "mathematica kernel for windows has stopped working". I don't know when this error will happen. Sometimes when I check the state of the running code, I encounter this error. and I need to choose the action "close the program" marked with the second arrow, and the kernel working currently will be closed and a new kernel starts and at last every thing goes fine again. The reason why a kernel will be started is because my code can realize this automatically when the working kernel fails. So all I want is a code which can close this dialog box by selecting the option "close the program" when error occurs.
[image: The dialog box in the center of the picture shows that "mathematica kernel for windows has stopped working". I don't know when this error will happen. Sometimes when I check the state of the running code, I find this error. and I need to choose the action "close the program" marked with the second arrow, and the kernel working currently will be closed and a new kernel starts and at last every thing goes fine again. The reason why a kernel will be started is because my code can realize this automatically when the working kernel fails. So all I want is a code which can close this dialog box by selecting the option "close the program" when error occurs.]

the second image shows the detailed information of two fails.
[image: the second image show the detailed information of two fails]

Comment: Hmm, a code dump, no context of what OP's trying to do… that certainly lowers the odds of anybody being interested in it.

Comment: how about now? thank you@J. M.

Comment: Without working code (here caused by lack of data/files),  reproduction is cumbersome if not impossible.

Comment: @YvesKlett I am sorry I don't understand "working code", do you mean what I want to do is difficult to realize?

Comment: We cannot evaluate your code because you rely on local files we don't have. So we cannot reproduce the problem. A self-contained example (all necessary code in the question) would be much more useful.

Comment: The dialog comes from the Windows Error Reporting system, you could try the steps detailed [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/) to just let the kernel process die without user intervention. It's unlikely that you can do anything in the Mathematica kernel itself because obviously the kernel is not working when this dialog appears.

Comment: @SimonWoods It's an excellent suggestion. I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: @YvesKlett Excuse me. I wonder how to upload my local rar file in which I put all necessary sample files. I uploaded the rar file into this share link of my online disk. <http://pan.baidu.com/s/1miplDyC>

Comment: It would be preferable to have a minimal working example here. Most users will not download unknown / potentially insecure files. If you can pinpoint the problem with a smaller code / data sample, all the better.

Comment: So what do you want? A: Suppress the Windows crash report dialog, or B: find the bug in your code? Because if A, than it is totally unnecessary to provide such a huge code dump, you can crash the kernel with way simpler code, e.g. `NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {}]}, x, {t, 0, 1}]`. Either A or B, please re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: @IstvánZachar  Thank you! I want A and I have got it with the method given by Simon Woods.

Comment: @YvesKlett Maybe my question is off-topic for this site indeed, so do i need delete this post?

Comment: Not sure. At the moment the question is closed and may be deleted in the future. You can leave it, try to edit to add more info / make it reproducible as suggested by some comments and request re-opening, or delete it - it is up to you.